# Android preview image crop

Tags: android, image, crop

I use this library https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop to crop image but i have a problem with the preview which is too small.i have this result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxVKA.png

How to fix this ? i used a samsung galaxy s4 and a samsung tab 3, and i also used other crop library but same problem.

Here is all i do to call the activity:

```
new Crop(source).output(outputUri).asSquare().start((Activity)context);
```

Comment: Have you checked your image source? You could be using its thumbnail. Just my guess.

Comment: thank you, i was using the thumbnail ^^

Answer (score 1):

I recommend another Image Crop library.

https://github.com/naver/android-imagecropview

please try this :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still stucked with this problem, here is the solution. The reason, why you are getting a small preview in the android-crop library, is that you are trying to work with a thumbnail of image, which you extract like `intent.getData()`. Don't do this, create a new empty file and set it's Uri in intent's extra with key `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Then, on `onActivityResult` just use android-crop library method `Crop.of()` with your Uri, that was setted on intent, and another Uri for a new cropped image.